# Twine GCP Artifact registry - HTTPError: 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, twine, google-artifact-registry

I am trying to upload private packages to a repository in my  Artifact Registry.
I'm using google cloud shell to upload a /dist from my package using twine.
Using the following tutorial https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/python/store-python

Trying to upload any package on my side using twine:

```
python3 -m twine upload --repository-url https://MY_REGION-python.pkg.dev/MY_PROJECT/MY_REPO dist/*
```

gives me :

> ERROR    HTTPError: 413 Request Entity Too Large from https://eu-west3-python.pkg.dev/membrane-94db9/nlpmodels
> Request Entity Too Large

even a 56.8 kB package gives me this error
Any idea how to increase this limit?
Thanks,

Comment: probably you already figured it out, for some reason GCP artifact registry (python repository) returns a 413 in scenarios where it should return a 400 or a 401. I don't really know whether this behavior is intentional (to hide information to the client) or a bug. Anyways I upvoted your question because I think it is valid.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and found out that this 413 is quite misleading.

In my case, the error was due to the repository URL. I mistakenly used the short name of the region for the MY_REGION token as it appears in your question. It would have make more sense to raise a 404.

However using the long name of the region solved the issue.